# Scaling criteria for Azure functions premium/consumption plan

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am working on a HttpTrigger based azure function and trying to figure out the scaling and cold start issues.

While looking into scaling, I found that the [azure function documentation](http://instances%20of%20the%20Azure%20Functions%20host%20are%20dynamically%20added%20and%20removed%20based%20on%20the%20number%20of%20incoming%20events) states that the

```
"instances of the Azure Functions host are dynamically added and removed based on the number of incoming events"
```

which has confused me as to how does the number of events determine the scaling out of function instances, as different function can be of different sizes in terms of how much compute power or memory they require to execute.

And where exactly can I find this "number of events" that supposedly triggers a new instance to be added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't find a specific "number of events," it's based on a wide variety of factors that Microsoft measures to determine the load of the currently running instances.  Functions that are grouped together in a single project and deployed as a single Function App on Azure scale together.  If you need functions that consume different levels of resources to scale independently, then be sure to deploy them as separate Function Apps (in the C#/VS world, that means different Projects).

If you have cold start issues, then the Premium plan can come into play. You pay for at least one instance to always be on and "pre-warmed" so that you never have cold starts.  The plan will then scale from there based on the previously mentioned "events" that Azure measures to determine if scaling out is needed.  MS has said that scaling out tends to be faster on the Premium Plan.  You also get a longer default function runtime on Premium if that is necessary (30min vs 5min).

Comment: thanks, I did end up doing the same, the "number of events" is still unknown, I tested a fairly simple task code, that ended up spawning 4 instances for just 10 requests (I expected only 1). Premium was way to go for my purpose.